# How can I target a specific elements scroll position within a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a basic wiki style page within a React site.  I'd like to fix the left nav in place when the scroll position has moved down by 100px.  I'm not sure the best method here and struggling a bit.

See my code so far below  - **basically the page itself - due to design - doesnt scroll** - the div with class **bodyText** has scroll-y and overflow applied

**<div className={`kb_nav ${this.state.activeClass}`}>** is where i'm trying to apply the releveant fix class at a particular scroll height.

I think where im going wrong is i need to target the scroll position of either the scrolling container or the kb_nav div within the scrolling container - not sure how to achieve this at the moment though - any advice would be great - thanks.

```
class Knowledge extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeClass:'',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){

      e.target.scrollTop.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

         let curClass = 'scroll';
         if(window.scrollY >= 100){
             curClass = 'fix_me';
         }
         this.setState({ activeClass: curClass});
         console.warn(curClass);
      });
  }

render() {
  return(

      <div className="App">


        {/* ===== CONTAINER'S ===== */}
        <div className="left_container_full"></div>


        <div className="strips">
          <div className="left_strip"></div>
          <div className="right_strip"></div>
        </div>


        <Header homepage={false} />

     

        <div className="bodyText fh kbase" id="baseRoot">
          <h2 className="first">Knowledge Base</h2>
          <p>
            <span>ArmourApp's Knowledge Base</span> is a series of support guide
            to help with any common issues. use the nav on the left to jump to a
            relevant section.

          </p>
          <div className="kb_wrapper">
            **<div className={`kb_nav ${this.state.activeClass}`}>**
              <h5>
                Sections: <span>(Click to jump)</span>
              </h5>
              <ul className="spanGroup">
                <li className="spanItem">
                  <a href="connectivity"   className="jumpTo">Connectivity</a>
                </li>
                <li className="spanItem">
                  <a href="" id="appaccess" className="jumpTo">App Access</a>
                </li>
                <li className="spanItem">
                  <a href="" className="jumpTo">App Crashing</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
             
       
            </div>
            <div className="kb_area">

              <div className="kb_area_wrap">
              <h5 id="connectivity">Connectivity:</h5>
              <button className="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
              <div className="collapsible-content">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </p>
              </div>
              <button className="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
              <div className="collapsible-content">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </p>
              </div>
                </div>
                <div className="kb_area_wrap">
                <h5 id="connectivit">Connectivity:</h5>
                <button className="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
                <div className="collapsible-content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <button className="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
                <div className="collapsible-content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </p>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="kb_area_wrap">
                  <h5 id="connectivity">Connectivity:</h5>
                  <button className="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
                  <div className="collapsible-content">
                    <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                      aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <button className="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
                  <div className="collapsible-content">
                    <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                      aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                  <div className="kb_area_wrap">
                <button className="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
                <div className="collapsible-content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        
        </div>

     
      </div>
  
  
  )
  };
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you achieve that with CSS and position: sticky?

Comment: indeed I could! - nice one @orel - saved me some pain there!  Happy to give you a tick as it does solve my issue if you want to log an answer.

Comment: No problem, I am going to do just that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with CSS by using `position: sticky;` on your left navigation bar